# warning in leaflet when adding polygon

Tags: leaflet

How to deal with a warning when I add polygons in leaflet using the following function:

```
metro %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addPolygons()
```

I received the following warning:

Warning message:
sf layer has inconsistent datum (+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs ).
Need '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'

Comment: Reproject your data.

Comment: How should I do that in rstudio using sp and leaflet? (sorry, I am new to using shapefiles in rstudio, using packages as sp and leaflet)

Comment: I think you should do that beforehand with GIS tools (my go-to tool would be GDAL's `ogr2ogr`). I'm not an expert on R or R Studio, but I suspect R is not the most appropriate tool to reproject geospatial data, and that `sf` expects data in a particular projection. In particular, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35590/reprojecting-vector-layer-in-qgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64878/using-ogr2ogr-to-reproject-and-rename-into-shapefile might be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks @IvanSanchez

Comment: The question has been answered and illustrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57223853/how-to-apply-spatial-polygons-to-leaflet-map-using-shp