# Shapefile Warnings in R

Tags: r

I tried importing a shapefile into R using the "sf" library:

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

sf <- sf::st_read("C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/shape5/shapefile.shp", options = "ENCODING=WINDOWS-1252") 

options:        ENCODING=WINDOWS-1252 
Reading layer `lda_000a16a_e' from data source `C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\shape5\shapefile.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 56590 features and 22 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 3658201 ymin: 658873 xmax: 9019157 ymax: 6083005
Projected CRS: PCS_Lambert_Conformal_Conic
```

When I try to plot this shapefile, I get the following warnings (no visualization was produced):

```
> leaflet()  %>% addTiles() %>%  addPolygons(data=sf,weight=5,col = 'red')
Warning messages:
1: sf layer is not long-lat data 
2: sf layer has inconsistent datum (+proj=lcc +lat_0=63.390675 +lon_0=-91.8666666666667 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +x_0=6200000 +y_0=3000000 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs).
Need '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84' 

Warning messages:
1: sf layer is not long-lat data 
2: sf layer has inconsistent datum (+proj=lcc +lat_0=63.390675 +lon_0=-91.8666666666667 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +x_0=6200000 +y_0=3000000 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs).
Need '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'
```

I tried to research the cause of these warnings over here ([How to apply spatial polygons to leaflet map using .shp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57223853/how-to-apply-spatial-polygons-to-leaflet-map-using-shp)) and tried to re-import this file using the following extension:

```
sf <- sf::st_read("C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents/shape5/shapefile.shp", options = "ENCODING=WINDOWS-1252") %>% %>%    sf::st_transform('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')
```

Now the visualization works fine.

- Does anyone know why this code now works?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Haven't worked with `leaflet` from R yet, but the warning seems quite distinct:

Your `sf` object from shapefile has the CRS `PCS_Lambert_Conformal_Conic`. You should be able to query the EPSG code using `st_crs(sf)$epsg`.

However, you need to reproject your data from the CRS in which your data is projected to lat/lon WGS 84 (EPSG: 4326). I assume this is some kind of restriction of Leaflet and on-the-fly projection doesn't work here.

This is achieved by `sf <- st_transform(sf, 4326)`. You should be able to continue without warnings now.

**Edit:**

It seems no langer advised to use proj4 string like `"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"` as CRS notation and e.g. input to `st_transform()`, but rather EPSG codes or WKT2 notations - c.f. [this article](https://inbo.github.io/tutorials/tutorials/spatial_crs_coding/).